# Alignment issues with desktop printer GC420d

Tags: printing, alignment, zebra-printer

I am having trouble with my desktop label printer model no: GC420d.
When I need to print a label, I make sure to choose the following print settings:
Choose correct Zebra printer
Choose print size of 3" x 2" as instructed.
The label prints too far off to the left, cutting half the words off!
Unsure if I need to reload the paper roll or if I'm doing anything else wrong??
Help!

Answer (score 0):

What was the file format used? word or pdf? If its word format, you better to try with pdf format, because sometimes word files give this kind of alignment problems.